# MemoryError when trying to append

Tags: python, out-of-memory

```
def get_user_info(user_id,info_type,u_access_token = None):

    if info_type == "user_friends":
        params = r"friends"
    elif info_type == "user_likes":
        params = r"likes"
    elif info_type == "user_feed":
        params = r"feed?
    fields=permalink_url,from,story,type,message,link,created_time,updated_time,likes.limit(0).summary(total_count),comments.limit(0).summary(total_count)"

    # To get the access token
    if u_access_token:
        FB_access_token = u_access_token
    else:
        FB_access_token = get_access_token.get_fb_token(glovar.APP_ID, glovar.APP_SECRET)

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(FB_access_token)

    user_info = graph.get_connections(user_id, params)

    if "Error" in user_info:
        print("Error", user_info["Error"]["message"])
        return []

    user_info_data = []
    while(user_info["data"]):
        if "Error" in user_info:
            print("Error", user_info["Error"]["message"])
            return []
        if "data" in user_info:
            try:
                for user_info_item in user_info["data"]:
                    if info_type == "user_feed":
                        # Convenience:Add empty field for message/link if not existent
                        user_info_item["message"] = user_info_item["message"] if "message" in user_info_item else ""
                        user_info_item["link"] = user_info_item["link"] if "link" in user_info_item else ""
                        user_info_data.append(user_info_item)
                        user_info = requests.get(user_info["paging"]["next"]).json()
                    elif info_type == "user_friends" or "user_likes":
                        user_info_data.append(user_info_item)
                        #if only one page or in the last page, ["paging"]["cursors"]["after"] is unrecognized code
                        if "https://graph.facebook.com" in user_info["paging"]["cursors"]["after"]:
                            user_info = requests.get(user_info["paging"]["cursors"]["after"]).json()

            except KeyError:
                break

    print(user_info_data)
```

The python program want to obtain may facebook account information, such as my friends,likes,feed...but running it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FBCrawl.py", line 254, in <module>
user_info_download.get_user_info(user_id,user_info_type,u_access_token)
File "C:\Python\PyCharmProject\FaceBookCrawl\user_info_download.py", line 51, in get_user_info
user_info_data.append(user_info_item)
MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It points to:

```
elif info_type == "user_friends" or "user_likes":
    user_info_data.append(user_info_item)
```

as the statement is causing the `MemoryError`. Please tell me why and how to correct it.

Comment: Sounds like the script is running out of memory. However there's not enough information in your question to say why. [_How to debug small programs_](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) might help you figure out the reason.

Comment: Are you using a 32bit python installation? Or using a 32bit computer? This error means you're out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an endless loop:

```
while(user_info["data"]):
```

Since new assignments to `user_info`:

```
user_info = requests.get(...
```

are all inside `if` statements that do not necessarily need to be true.

At the same time, you keep append to a list in this loop:

```
user_info_data.append(user_info_item)
```

Make sure that `user_info["data"]` really becomes false at a some point in time.

This is the problem code:

```
elif info_type == "user_friends" or "user_likes":
    user_info_data.append(user_info_item)
    if "https://graph.facebook.com" in user_info["paging"]["cursors"]["after"]:
        user_info = requests.get(user_info["paging"]["cursors"]["after"]).json()
```

You append to `user_info_data`. But if `if "https://graph.facebook.com" in user_info["paging"]["cursors"]["after"]` if false, you will loop without updating `user_info`. Next loop will be exactly the same. So you keep looping and adding the same thing to `user_info_data` until you use up all available memory.

Comment: Does this answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This elif statement

`elif info_type == "user_friends" or "user_likes":`

governs how many items are appended to the offending list. However the elif condition will ALWAYS evaluate as a true value and cause unwanted data to be appended to the list.

Correct code: 
`elif info_type == "user_friends" or info_type == "user_likes":`

Note: this problem is additional to that described in the answer by @Mike ... both problems need to be fixed.